# Is there a way to enable touch-hold image save in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Ok so in mobile safari you can pull up a web page and touch and hold on an image to save it to the iPhone's photo library.  In a UIWebview on a view this does not happen (it pops up the alt-text and never prompts you).  I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to turn this feature on.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it (on tap) would be to

1. grab the content
2. Do smart img tag finding to find all img tags
3. find / replace with a link to some arbitrary place http://foo.com?REAL_IMG_SRC
4. overload `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` in your delegate
5. intercept all links that contain foo.com
6. Use the REAL_IMG_SRC to download/present save options/etc...

Comment: what do you mean by real_image_src? could you provide some concrete examples?

Comment: REAL_IMAGE_SOURCE is the address of the image source. "http://server.com/image.png" or whatever.

Comment: This is nice for on top, is there a way to do it so it will try to grab the URL of the image on press and hold (Javascript maybe)?

Comment: Also do you have to do things to the document.domain when modifying the HTML of a page?